# TTS randomly skips first letters of sentence

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have an app for people with low vision that relies heavily on TTS. However for some reason when I use the speak method TTS randomly skips the first few letters of a sentence or speaks the first few letters in a ver low volume and the rest in a normal volume.

Any idea why this might happen?

This is my current code:

```
public class SpeechHelper implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private Context context = null;
    private TextToSpeech tts;

    public SpeechHelper(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        try {
            tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Phone Features Exception","Couldn't initiate TTS", e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
        }
    }

    public void speak(String s, int mode, String messageID) {

        Log.d("VOLUME", "getStreamVolume " + am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)); // Always 15
        Log.d("VOLUME", "isMusicActive " + (am.isMusicActive() ? "true" : "false")); // Always false
        Log.d("VOLUME", "isVolumeFixed " + (am.isVolumeFixed() ? "true" : "false")); // Always false
        Log.d("VOLUME", "isSpeakerphoneOn: " + (am.isSpeakerphoneOn() ? "true" : "false")); // Always false
        Log.d("VOLUME", "getMode: " + am.getMode()); // Always 0

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, messageID);
        tts.speak(s, mode, params);
    }
}
```

I've noticed the problem always happens on the next 5 seconds after making a call or when unlocking the phone to the app.

Comment: Which engine are you testing against?

Comment: I've noticed this always happens after making a call. Any clues? what do you mean with which engine?

Comment: @ozbek I'm using com.google.android.tts

Answer (score 1):

Either you are doing something wrong or Android is doing something wrong. If I had to put money on it I would say it is you.

Start by just calling

```
tts.speak("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", tts.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

to see if you can reproduce the problem in a test app (I couldn't). If you can, then I'd be very curious as to what phone/OS you are running on . Your problem probably lies with truncated strings, or something else programmatically messing with volume.

Comment: I've been printing the strings and they don't seem to have any problems. I have noticed the problem always happens after making a call, but I haven't been able to fix it yet.

Comment: What Phone/OS are you using?

Comment: @lisovaccaro Have you been able to figure out the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase Expressive Breaks in setting. It may be to fast so it ship it. It should work as I just solved the problem in this way. Let me know